# NSURLConnection Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1008

Tags: nsurlconnection

When I type the url in a browser it works.
When I tried from my program, I have an error.
I have no idea why. And you ?

```
NSString *urlString ;
urlString = @"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString] ;

NSLog(@"--urlString      %@",urlString);
NSLog(@"--absoluteString %@",[url  absoluteString]);
NSLog(@"--host %@",[url  host]);
NSLog(@"--path %@",[url  path]);
NSLog(@"--pathExtension %@",[url  pathExtension]);
NSLog(@"--query %@",[url  query]);
NSLog(@"--scheme %@",[url  scheme]);
NSLog(@"--port %@",[url  port]);
NSLog(@"--parameterString %@",[url  parameterString]);

NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad timeoutInterval:30] ;
NSURLResponse *resp = nil ;

NSError *error = nil ;
NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:req returningResponse:&resp error:&error] ;
NSLog(@"initWithAdresse 1");
if ( error ) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error) ;
}
```

And I get the following error :
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1008 "resource unavailable" UserInfo=0x6000002e5000
......

[EDIT]
ILario got it !

the solution is to write :

```
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                     cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly timeoutInterval:30] ;
```

But as I wanted only to get xml from the url, one can use :

```
parser  = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url] ;
```

There is also :

```
NSString *result = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] ;
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: try to change:  cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad with: cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowedInMemoryOnly